# Delphi equivalent to Ctrl+K+D in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, delphi, delphi-7, code-formatting

Does Delphi 7 have the Ctrl K D option like Visual Studio to format the code ie/tidy it up and put all the indents etc in the right place?

Comment: Visual Studio 6 doesn't have this feature either!

Comment: ...but VS2005, 2008, 2010 does

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Delphi 2010 and later, Ctrl+D will activate the built-in formatter - but before then, there was no such feature in the IDE.

For Delphi 7, you will have to use a third-party plugin which provides a formatter.

Answer (score 3):

For earlier versions of Delphi there is an "experimental" build of the GExperts plugin which has a configurable code formatter. It is available from [TWM's website](http://www.dummzeuch.de/english.html).

I have been using it to tidy up some inconsistently formatted code (written by multiple developers, none of who used MY layout style (based on the old [Borland Style Guide](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10280))

Comment: Thanks @Johnny. I wasn't aware that the stand-alone version was still available. I'm a GExperts fan anyway, so the "experimental" build suits me.

Comment: I already have GExperts installed but not a experimental build. Whats the hassle involved uninstalling and installing the experimental version

Comment: I use the GExperts version too. The stand-alone version doesn't understand the strict keyword...

Answer (score 0):

You may use the  very efficient [JEDI code format](http://jedicodeformat.sourceforge.net/).
I use it as an external tool, but a Delphi IDE pluggin can be installed for Delphi 7.
For use as an external tool :
1/ download the  [jcf_243_exe.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jedicodeformat/files/)
2/ unzip it in a directory
3/ run the JCFGui.exe : choose your project directory (save it before) and look the results !
4/ you may change the code format rules in the menu 'settings'/'Format settings'

Comment: Can it, the build I used only did Delphi 11/12. Do you have a link?

Comment: @Jon i'm not sure to understand your question but :  you can use it as an external tool (http://sourceforge.net/projects/jedicodeformat/files/) with every Delphi version.